# How do I set default player names, nations and AI difficulty?

Tags: freeciv

When I want to start a new game of Freeciv, I am always presented with a screen like this:

[image: Freeciv start game]

I want to set some defaults so that I don't have to manually select the player nations every time I want to start a new game (this becomes tedious when the number of players is 30+).

I know how to set the default number of AI players (by using the `aifill` server option). But how can I set the default AI skill level, the default player names, and the default player nations?

In other words, I'd like to be automatically presented with something like this when I want to start a new game:

[image: Freeciv pre-selected nations]

How can I achieve this?

EDIT: Freeciv issue tracker: https://www.hostedredmine.com/issues/855495

Answer (score 1):

The default AI level can be set with the `hard` server command. You can set it in a file with server commands and start Freeciv with the `-r` option to read that file.

A default player name or default nations cannot be set, as far as I'm aware, but my Freeciv knowledge is rusty.

Answer (score 0):

The server file or CLI can help you setup players

there are commands for levels of difficulty

- **hard**
- **normal**
- **easy**
  commands like that

there are also commands for the number of AI players that appear by default
**set aifill 3**
makes sure that AI players will fill up the number players to 3

if you set that value to zero
**set aifill 0**
you can create new AI players as well and depending on the build, set the AI package for a player and a name for the player

**create [name] [aitype]**
allows you to create a player with [name] and then give it a particular [aitype], such as *classic*, for instance

Hope that helps

Comment: What version of Freeciv are you using?

Comment: I had built freeciv from the github distribution

Freeciv version 3.0.92.1-dev